# tooltip messes up bar chart in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart.js to create a stacked bar chart and while I have succeed to move and rotate the xaxis labels to be shown on the top of the bars, when I use mouse to move over the bars, the whole chart appears distorted. [image]

this is the normal
and this is what i get after mouse over:
[image]

here is the code

this is what i use to rotate xaxis labels:

https://jsfiddle.net/staverist/zhocr17t/96/

```
animation: {
                        duration: 1,
                        onComplete: function() {
                        var chartInstance = this.chart;
                            var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                            ctx.textAlign = "left";
                            ctx.font = "bold 10px Arial";
                            ctx.fillStyle = "black";                            
                            Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                                    var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                    Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                                            ctx.save();
                                            // Translate 0,0 to the point you want the text
                                            ctx.translate(bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 30);
                                        // Rotate context by -90 degrees
                                        ctx.rotate(-0.5 * Math.PI);
                                                    // Draw text
                              //ctx.fillText(value,0,0);
                               if(bar._datasetIndex==0){            
                               ctx.fillText(bar._model.label, 0, 0);
                                             ctx.restore();
                               }
                                    }),this)
                            }),this);
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not restoring the canvas state after rotating it. Instead of restoring it inside the `if` statement, you should restore it outside, like so :

```
...
if (bar._datasetIndex == 0) {
   ctx.fillText(bar._model.label, 0, 0);
}
ctx.restore(); //<- restore canvas state
...
```

also, you should better create a [plugin](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html) (to prevent label flickering), instead of drawing the labels on animation complete.

Here is the [**working example on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nfy3upmm/)